# Why does the object I added to a JavaScript array come back as undefined when I read it back immediately after adding it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I realise this code is very ugly but I'm having some trouble with `JavaScript`.  I cannot see why the following `child` is not `a task to derive from`:

```
          var childrenToOperateOn = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.derivedTasksToIndent.length; i++) {
            if($scope.derivedTasksToIndent[i].todosernm == todo.todosern){
              childrenToOperateOn.push($scope.derivedTasksToIndent[i]);
              console.log("Affecting child: " + $scope.derivedTasksToIndent[i].todotask);

              for (var child in childrenToOperateOn) {
                console.log("Confirm child: " + child.todotask);
              }
            }
          }
```

Instead, when I try to read the value back from the `childrenToOperateOn` array I get `undefined`:

```
(index):145 Affecting child: A task to derive from
(index):147 Confirm child: undefined
```

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm using `AngularJS` as is probably obvious.

How would I retain the proper value and it's properties?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for ... of` instead of `for ... in`.

```
for (var child of childrenToOperateOn) {
    console.log("Confirm child: " + child.todotask);
}
```

> Both for..of and for..in statements iterate over lists; the values iterated on are different though, for..in returns a list of keys on the object being iterated, whereas for..of returns a list of values of the numeric properties of the object being iterated.

More information here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html